# Installable code playground

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle, jsbin

I am looking for an installable code playground, possibly for HTML, CSS and Javascript.

I am a computer science professor and in one of my courses I teach basic HTML, CSS and some Javascript. I would like to introduce my students to code playgrounds such as jsfiddle or jsbin. Additionally, I would like to deliver final exams through a similar tool, so that we replace tests written on paper with tests performed, self-assessed and refined on a browser-based tool.

The problem is that I do not want to let students access the Internet during the exam, and look for existing answers online or even establish communication channels among themselves or with experts at home, so I need to isolate the lab from Internet during the exams.

This means that I need to install a local copy of the playground tool on one of my servers. Do you know of any tool that provides their code (free or commercially, not relevant) for a local installation?

I don't need anything fancy, no automatic includes, no libraries, nothing special, just the possibility to install something on my server that runs without Internet dependencies.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsbin https://github.com/jsbin/jsbin/ can be run locally on a Node server. You need Node/npm installed first but after that it is easy. As long as you don't need libraries it can run without a network connection (just tried it) but the libraries seem to be external paths by default.